# SceneKit detect when SCNode is not moving

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

In my scene I throw in a ball. I want to remove my ball when it stops moving. My ball has a dynamic physics body and is performing collisions as it should etc.

What I want to do is fade out my ball from the scene when it has stopped moving. I call a function on my ball when its Z velocity equals 0 as in zero stopped moving.

```
func removeBowlingBallWhenNotMoving() {
        guard let bowlingBallNode = bowlingBallNode else {return}
        if let bowlingBallZVelocity = bowlingBallNode.physicsBody?.velocity.z {
            if Int(bowlingBallZVelocity) == 0 {
                performFadeOutOnBowlingBallWith(duration: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is called in **didSimulatePhysicsAtTime**: (which is called 60fps as I understand it)

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        bowlingBall.removeBowlingBallWhenNotMoving()
    }
```

The issue I am having is that obviously the balls Z velocity starts at zero and is removed right away. I only want to fade it out when it reaches 0 not starts at 0. I can see in the log:

```
Alex 0
Alex 0
Alex 0
Alex 0
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -2
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex -1
Alex 0
```

Am I performing this in the correct delegate function and if so how do ignore its starting velocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the node you place it in the real world by `node.position = SCNVector3Make(x,y,originZ)` that will become the start point. so if you do it like this:

```
if let bowlingBallZVelocity = bowlingBallNode.physicsBody?.velocity.z, bowlingBallNode.position.z != originZ {
            if Int(bowlingBallZVelocity) == 0 {
                performFadeOutOnBowlingBallWith(duration: 1.0)
            }
        }
```

It will prevent you from making it disappear in the first pixel.

You can also prevent it from happening by comparing your current `worldposition` and the nodes `worldposition`

Comment: Thank you your implementation it guided me in the right direction of checking the nodes current position is also not 0 as well as the velocity. if zPositionOfBowlingBall != 0 && Int(bowlingBallZVelocity) == 0 {
            performFadeOutOnBowlingBallWith(duration: 1.0)
        }

Answer (score 1):

SceneKit exposes the [`isResting`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514795-isresting) property:

> SceneKit’s physics simulation may automatically set it to YES if the
>   body is not moving and not affected by any forces.

Comment: I did try this and found other users trying to use this property but it always returns false whether the node is moving or not. Any suggestion on why that could be?